# css white-space:nowrap horizontal scroll bug

Tags: css, whitespace, horizontal-scrolling, nowrap

I have the following markup

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer
    {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    #inner
    {
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
        margin:0px 4px 0px 4px;
        padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;
        border:1px solid #9A9A9A;
        border-width:1px 1px 0px 1px;
    }

</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
    </div>
</div>
```

When the browser is wide enough, it looks like this
[image: wide]

When the browse is resized narrow, it looks like this
[image: narrow]

I want the gray background of the narrow view to extend all the way to the right when I scroll. What about my markup and css is causing this unwanted effect (occurs in Chrome, FF3 and IE8)

Comment: +1 This even happens with Facebook!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy solution is to do this: on `#outer`, remove `width: 100%` and add `float: left`.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCuJT/)

Comment: What should I do if I don't want to float left?

Comment: @NathanGould: That's hard to answser without knowing *why* you don't want to use `float: left`. You can use `display: inline-block` instead, if that helps.