# Content of divs inside a parent with "overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap" overflowing out of their background

Tags: css, overflow

With the following HTML/CSS markup ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ksMEp/)),

```
<div style="border:solid 1px red; width:200px;padding:10px;padding-right:0;overflow-x:scroll;">
    <div style="width:100%;background:yellow;">text text text text text text text</div>
    <div style="width:100%;background:yellow;">text text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

the content of the inner divs will wrap automatically. I don't want that. However, if I use `white-space: nowrap` on the outer div, the yellow background color of the inner divs does not extend to the end of their content.

How can I fix this markup so that the content of the inner divs doesn't wrap *and* all of their content is shown on the yellow background?

Comment: Your requirement sounds somewhat controversial. What do you mean by the words not wrapping automatically? And what kind of background not fitting do you have?

Comment: I just don't want the words break.

Comment: how to make the children stretched?

Comment: Check this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964041/css-white-spacenowrap-horizontal-scroll-bug

Comment: Vikas: the answer is not same as. see http://jsfiddle.net/9gyGG/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that [seems to do what I think you're asking for](http://jsfiddle.net/ksMEp/20/):

```
<div style="border:solid 1px red; width:200px;padding:10px;padding-right:0;overflow-x:scroll;white-space:nowrap">
    <div style="display:inline-block;min-width:100%;background:yellow;">text text text text text text text</div><br>
    <div style="display:inline-block;min-width:100%;background:yellow;">text text text text</div>
</div>
```

Notice the `display: inline-block` property, the use of `min-width` instead of `width`, and the `<br>` tag between the divs.

Honestly, though, this feels like a really ugly kluge.  I can't help but think that there *must* be a better way to achieve this result.

Comment: Thank you for correct my Eglish. Your answer helps. But I preffer to change my layout instead using the css hacker.

Comment: I finally decided using js to avoid this bug