# Problems with the footer; When I resize the window there's a large whitespace to the right

Tags: html, css

Okay so this has been bugging me for a few hours and not only can't I solve this but I'm not understanding why it's doing this (It's 6am to be fair @_@). Anyways, so I'm trying to make the footer continuous, a simple colour. And the footer content consists of a few vertical boxes of varying widths. I am using an unordered list with lists in order to accomplish this.

http://jsfiddle.net/WTABE/

Everything is okay when the browser is maxed, but when I resize it a horizantal scroll bar appears and when you scroll right the page cuts off and further right of it is a large whitespace.

Now whenever I take out the width in #footerContect ul {} this problem simply goes away but the columns un-center themselves. And even when I adjust the individual widths of the li> contents themselves it makes little impact on the size of the whitespace. And even when I shtrink down the li> components to widths of 50px and the UL width to 500px (I did it to see what would happen), the white space is still there!

There must be something I'm missing here because I also tried putting the margins and paddings of the li> to zero and they all smush up together but the white space remains.

Comment: OKAY. Well this is embarrassing.... I simply took out--

 #footerContent #LIquicknav {width:100px;} 

#footerContent #quicknav li {float:none; width:150px;}​

And it worked O_O;; I'm still curious why taking those two out fixed it. They seemingly added a thousand extra pixels out of nowhere.

Comment: I NARROWED it down specifically to this line of code--- the float:none;  I left EVERYTHING else intact except I removed that from #quicknavli... Anyone have any idea why that would add like 500px worth of white space? I tried float:right and it seemed to have the same whitespace effect as float:none;! I tried float:left and the whitespace was gone.... float:none = float:right;?

Comment: Can you add html code to your fiddle? :)

Comment: It's quite messy! http://jsfiddle.net/WTABE/2/ It's uh, pretty ugly code to be honest. I need to get better with that >.<

Answer (score 0):

OKAY. So I figured out it had something to do with the floats, I simply took out the float from:

## footerContent #quicknav li {float:none; width:150px;}​

And now it looks perfect on chrome.

But IE and Firefox are really giving me problems. If you adjust the size of the browser the footer adjusts and gets stuck... As in when you scroll right with the horizantal bar you leave the footer where you left it. To the left. And there's some weird extra whitespacing going on again. This has to do undoubetdbly with more of the floats (Tried putting a border on all the elements, and eliminated one DIV section at a time until most of the whitespacing disappeared).

This guy did not use floats but that's how my browser looks in IE or firefox:
[css white-space:nowrap horizontal scroll bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964041/css-white-spacenowrap-horizontal-scroll-bug)

Comment: Okay so I solved it by putting min-width:960px; on the footer background but I'm unsatisfied because I don't know why that worked. Well I sorta do... But I don't get why that worked and putting a width down didn't, isn't putting width down essentially the same as saying min-width? And also, I thought this was a float/collapse problem. The container DIV was not adjusting to the floated elements size because they're taken out of normal flow to begin with. I'll try to solve this a different prettier way.